# symmetry breaking predicates in Alloy

Tags: alloy

Say I have a simple model as follows:
    sig P{r:some P}
    sig Q{}
 run {} for 2 P, 2 Q

Does anyone here know how alloy generates symmetry breaking predicates to reduce the number of instances for this model?

Answer (score 3):

Alloy itself relies on another relational model finder called Kodkod as its backend. Kodkod generates symmetry breaking predicates using a technique called greedy base partitioning, which is detailed in Emina Torlak's thesis (chapter 3):

http://people.csail.mit.edu/emina/pubs/kodkod.phd.pdf

Comment: Okay, say you have relational constants e1 and e2 which capture the relation over a1 and a2, and the symmetry is (a1,a2). I know the symmetry can be broken among a1 and a2, but what about the relational constants e1 and e2, is there a symmetry there, how can you break this symmetry then?